# How to use .htaccess to make a subfolder act as a subdomain

Tags: htaccess

I have to make a new site for every subdomain I want to add directly on my host, so I'd like to make them subfolders and redirect like this so they look like subdomains anyway.

For example, how could I (or could I at all?) use .htaccess to do the following:

Make
-website.com/subfolder/
into
-subfolder.website.com/

Is this possible?

Comment: This is done in the virtual hosts not the htaccess file.